# Dynamic HTML not displaying at respective place

Tags: plugins, posts, shortcode

Dynamic HTML not displaying at respective place
I have a created shortcode in `function.php` and my code is,

```
function Post_home(){
$data='<div class="cp-seeWrapper"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';

  //some logic here

  $data.='</div>';
  $data.='<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="cp-social">';
            if (is_active_sidebar('footer-social')) :
                 dynamic_sidebar('footer-social');
                endif;
  $data.='</div><div class="cp-newsletter">';
           if (is_active_sidebar('cp_newsletter')) :
                 dynamic_sidebar('cp_newsletter');
                endif;
  $data.='</div></div></div></div></div>';
 return $data;    
}
add_shortcode( 'home_post', 'Post_home' );
```

Now just notice here, Whatever I am adding the logic part that output is displaying before the parent div. I mean my parent div is `cp-seeWrapper` and output is displaying before it.

I added footer-social and newsletter logic and both are displaying above parent div.

Would you help me out?

**My output is**

```
//I am getting my output here
    <div class="cp-seeWrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="cp-social"></div>
            <div class="cp-newsletter"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**I have created widget on `function.php`**

```
function cp_newsletters() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Newsletter',
        'id'            => 'cp_newsletter',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-newsletter">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-newsletter_title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'cp_newsletters' );
```

Comment: If your shortcode function needs to echo the output, then you should use [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2832010). And I said so because `dynamic_sidebar()` echoes the sidebar's widgets.

Comment: @SallyCJ, So I have to add ob_start();?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I have created a widget in function.php (Code added in the question.) and then I am calling on another function.

Comment: Yes, call `ob_start()` as in my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the output there because [`dynamic_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dynamic_sidebar/) displays/echoes the output (widgets in the specific sidebar), so the output is echoed right when the shortcode function is called, which is before the `$data` is actually echoed.

And you can fix that using [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2832010):

1. Either append the output to `$data`:

   ```php
   $data.='</div>';
   $data.='<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="cp-social">';
   if (is_active_sidebar('footer-social')) :
       ob_start();
       dynamic_sidebar('footer-social'); // echoes the widgets
       $data .= ob_get_clean();          // append the output
   endif;
   $data.='</div><div class="cp-newsletter">';
   if (is_active_sidebar('cp_newsletter')) :
       ob_start();
       dynamic_sidebar('cp_newsletter'); // echoes the widgets
       $data .= ob_get_clean();          // append the output
   endif;
   $data.='</div></div></div></div></div>';
   ```

   You can turn on/off output buffering at anytime, and you should do the same as above with the `cp_newsletter` sidebar.

   ***Update:*** Not sure why this option is not working for you, but maybe the updated code can help?
2. Or (maybe easier), echo everything in your function:

   ```php
   function Post_home() {
       ob_start();
       ?>
           <div class="cp-seeWrapper">
             <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                   <div class="cp-social">
                     <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'social-footer' ) ) dynamic_sidebar( 'social-footer' ); ?>
                   </div>
                   <div class="cp-newsletter">
                     <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'cp_newsletter' ) ) dynamic_sidebar( 'cp_newsletter' ); ?>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
       <?php
       return ob_get_clean();
   }
   ```

### UPDATE

For option #1, you might want to consider caching either the widgets (i.e. the output returned by the `ob_get_clean()` call) or your shortcode output (i.e. the entire content of the `$data`). I suggested that for performance reasons where the shortcode *could* be called twice or more on the same page.

Additionally, if you're going to use option #2 (echo everything), then you might want to consider creating a template and do something like:

```php
function Post_home() {
    ob_start();
    locate_template( 'my-template.php', true );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Which one is the best answer?

Comment: That would depend on your code, but whichever is easier for you, just go with it. And if you need further assistance in deciding the best, SO is a better place for that. So if the answer helps, you can either accept it or upvote it..

Comment: Yes, I tried first one and it's working for me. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Thanks, and perhaps the revised answer can help (with that first option not working)..

Comment: thanks for the help again.