# Next and Previous Pagination button not displaying in WordPress

Tags: plugins, posts, shortcode, pagination

I have more than 15 posts and I am displaying only 6 per page load and remaining will display after the click on the pagination but the issue is I am not getting my pagination.

**I am using below code**

```
function recentPost_on_home(){
ob_start();
?>
<div class="cp-seeWrapper"><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="row">
   <?php $args = array('posts_per_page' => 6);
            $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
                while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $tyler_query->the_post();
            $categories = get_the_category(); $names = ''; if ( $categories && is_array( $categories )) { foreach ( $categories as $cat ) { $names .= $cat->name . ' '; } }?>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="cp-shadow cp-seeSinglePostWrapper">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?>
                        <div class="bg-white single-post-box">
                            <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
                                <div class="seeDate"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y');?></div>
                                <?php echo $names;?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cp-heading"><h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>" class="seePost_title"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 10, '...');?></a></h3></div>
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 20, '...');?></p>
    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <?php  }?>
    <div class="nav-previous alignleft">hello<?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
   <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php echo previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
    <?php       }?>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <!--some logic here-->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <?php return ob_get_clean(); 
}
add_shortcode( 'home_recent_post', 'recentPost_on_home' );
```

The second issue is, I am getting all the categories of the single product, I have to display only 2 categories.

For example, product is IOS and categories are iPhone and iMac,iPod. So I have to display iPhone and iMac only.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for and is not clear why you use the buffer.

Does "After 'click'" means client-side scripting?

Or you have to create some additional pages for categories? Did you do this?

Comment: @MaxYudin, Sorry for the late reply, I am using buffer because I was getting some issue with HTML. My output was displaying before the parent div. Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/351688/dynamic-html-not-displaying-at-respective-place/351692?noredirect=1#comment513583_351692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a custom query (`new WP_Query`), so you need to pass `$tyler_query->max_num_pages` (the max pages) to the `next_posts_link()` function — more details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_posts_link/#comment-1297):

```php
next_posts_link( null, $tyler_query->max_num_pages )
```

And btw, no need to `echo` with `previous_posts_link()` because the function indeed echoes the output. I.e. Just do so: `<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>`.

Also, you should add `paged` to your query args (`$args`):

```php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);

$tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But if you're using the shortcode on a single post or Page, `previous_posts_link()` wouldn't work since it relies upon a global variable named `$paged` which is set only for archive-based requests such as search results. To make `$paged` works on single requests or with `previous_posts_link()`, you can try:

```php
global $paged;
$paged = $paged ? $paged : get_query_var( 'page' );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
```

> For example, product is IOS and categories are iPhone and iMac,iPod.
>   So I have to display iPhone and iMac only.

So after discussing via chat (to get more details about the above), you can use the following if you want to display the name of the first two of the categories: (which could actually be just one)

```php
$names = array();
$categories = get_the_category();
//shuffle( $categories ); // uncomment if you want random entries
foreach ( $categories as $i => $term ) {
    if ( $i < 2 ) { // show at most two
        $names[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $term->term_id ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
}
$names = implode( ', ', $names );
```

And that would replace the `$categories = get_the_category(); $names = ''; if ( $categories && is_array( $categories )) { foreach ( $categories as $cat ) { $names .= $cat->name . ' '; } }`.

See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) for more details about `get_category_link()`.

### Additional Notes

**You should call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/)** after your custom loop ends: `while ( ... ) { ... } wp_reset_postdata();`. Or after the `have_posts()` block ends: `if ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) { ... } wp_reset_postdata();`.

Doing that would restore the global `$post` variable to the current post in the main query (contained in the global `$wp_query` variable as opposed to your `$tyler_query` variable). And this restoration is necessary in order for template tags like `the_title()` to work in terms of referencing to the current post in the main query.

Comment: It's working perfectly for me.  I really appreciate your support. Thanks for the help..upvote from my side.

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Comment: Can you help me out in this solution? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354486/search-not-working-with-title-and-content